# JSON WCF display blank page in C#

Tags: c#, json, wcf

I create a Console Application to be a WCF.

My class ISimpleService

```
[ServiceContract()]
public interface ISimpleService
{
    [OperationContract]
    Person GetData(string id); 
}
```

My class SimpleService

```
public class SimpleService:ISimpleService
{
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", 
                ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
                UriTemplate = "data/{id}")]
    public Person GetData(string id)
    {
        // lookup person with the requested id 
        return new Person()
                   {
                       Id = Convert.ToInt32(id), 
                       Name = "Leo Messi"
                   };
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

My Program Class

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        //Create a URI to serve as the base address
        var httpUrl = new Uri("http://localhost:8090/MyService/SimpleService");
        //Create ServiceHost
        var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(SimpleService), httpUrl);
        //Add a service endpoint
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ISimpleService)
        , new WSHttpBinding(), "");
        //Enable metadata exchange
        var smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior
        {
            HttpGetEnabled = true
        };
        host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
        //Start the Service
        host.Open();

        Console.WriteLine("Service is host at " + DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        Console.WriteLine("Host is running... Press <Enter> key to stop");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

My problem is that when I go to http://localhost:8090/MyService/SimpleService/data/5 , it displays a blank page. I debug the method GetData(string id) and it doesn't run this method. How to solve it?

Comment: You're trying to use `wsHttpBinding` for a RESTFUL service, and you're treating the service like a SOAP service.  Try using `webHttpBinding` instead.

Comment: It displays a message: The message with To 'http://localhost:8090/MyService/SimpleService/data/3' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to an AddressFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher.  Check that the sender and receiver's EndpointAddresses agree.
Can you solve it?

Comment: I just gave you a pointer in the right direction - use `webHttpBinding`, not `wsHttpBinding`.  `webHttpBinding` is designed for RESTful WCF, whereas `wsHttpBinding` is for SOAP.  You're doing REST, so use the correct binding.

Comment: Yes, I use `webHttpBinding`. But it displays message above.

Comment: Are you using `webHttpBinding` on both the service and the client?  Post your client code, please.

Comment: I dont use client. I created a Service and when I go to 'localhost:8090/MyService/SimpleService/data/3', simply I want to display json file like {"id":3, "Name":"Leo Messi"}